# How can I access list of list in Python?

Tags: python

Here is some code that I wrote:

```
class supClass:
    supList=[]
    def __init__(self):
        ""

class MyClass:
    listt=[]
    code=None
    def __init__(self):
        ""  

instancelist = [ MyClass() for i in range(4)]
for i in range(0,4):
    instancelist[i].listt.append(supClass())
    instancelist[i].listt.suplist.append(i)
    instancelist[i].code=12


for i in range(4):
    print instancelist[0].listt.suplist
```

It produces the following error:

```
  File "/home/aj/workspace/PythonTutorials/basics/builtFun.py", line 21, in <module>
    instancelist[i].listt.suplist.append(i)
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'suplist'
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `listt` is a list, therefore, you need to index it (i.e. select an item from the list as in) before calling that item's method. (e.g. `instancelist[0].listt[0].supList`) I'm still not sure why you have a list with only one item in it, however.
2. Capitalization matters. You want `supList.append()`, not `suplist.append()`.

Comment: This answer misses that `listt` is a `list` and a `supClass` item must be retrieved from it before calling `supList.append()`.

Comment: @Johnsyweb: Oh good point. I didn't catch that.

Answer (score 1):

I'm having difficulty understanding what your code is trying to achieve, but this fixes your syntax errors:

```
for i in range(4):
    instancelist[i].listt.append(supClass())
    # listt is a list object. To access the last item, use [-1]. 
    # supList has a capital L.
    instancelist[i].listt[-1].supList.append(i)
    instancelist[i].code = 12

for i in range(4):
    # It looks like you want to print the supList for each supClass item in list:
    print [s.supList for s in instancelist[0].listt]
```

Comment: thanks a lot its worked .,.for my project i want to append something similar to like this

Comment: I'm glad it worked, but I still don't understand this code or the code in your previous question.